# Script debugging on AJAX base web application. Can I bypass my dependent module test script execution in Eclipse?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, eclipse, integration-testing, ajax

I'm testing a web application in which all web controls are loaded dynamically using AJAX. I have a test script project in java Eclipse IDE.

Here is my problem. If, for example, I am debugging a test script for my last module, I have to go through all my dependent modules first and execute each one's script before I can debug my last module. It is a very time consuming and boring task to execute the scripts for previous modules every time.

Is there a way I can bypass my dependent module test script execution in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Your dependent code should be moved to a method in a [POM](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp#page-object-design-pattern) that is called by any test(s) that needs it. For example, a login method in the LoginPage POM can be called by any test as a first step for an authenticated test case flow.

Comment: Let say my ItemFillUp page is there which can not be open unless I login to my system, But now as my case ItemFillUp page is release and under testing so I am creating script for that. In this ItemFillUp module there is one another AJEX Window. I directly wants to get my script launch this window once I open the ItemFillUp page.

Comment: Your Test would look something like: Login(), then NavigateTo(ItemFillUp), and then OpenAjaxWindow();

Comment: Yes, it same like you said.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar problem,Now what I will do is put debugger in catch block and drag it up if any case fails. Also we can use JavaScript to validate web element interactions. Something like `document.getElementById("id").click()` from browser console.